# Windows phone 8.1 Toast brings you to a certain page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, toast

I'm working on a **windows 8.1** app that Polls for errors at a Restserver.
If the server returns x amount of errors, i would like to **display x amount of toasts.** 
I already found the way to do this but not the following:

I want so that if you **click** on a toast, a **certain page is launched with params that are linked to the Toast**.
Analog to Android where you can put an intent with extras to a toast.

Documentation tells me if the toast is clicked i get sent to the overridden Onlaunch method... somewhere.
If i click it i just enter the page that is last used.

Hope this question is clear,
Sincere greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click the toast the `OnLaunched` method in `App` class will still be called.

So if you want to execute some logic based on your toast notifications, you should check the `args.Arguments` property in this method. This property will have a value only when you set some data in the `launch` attribute on your toast XML.

The code is like this in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
  string launchString = args.Arguments;

  ....
}
```

and your toast payload:

```
<toast launch="My_Parameter">                        
<visual>
    <binding template="ToastImageAndText01">
        <image id="1" src="ms-appx:///images/redWide.png" alt="red graphic"/>
        <text id="1">Hello World!</text>
    </binding>
</visual>
```

Comment: Yes i know that its sended to "App" class. could you point me out where this class is located ? cause when i click it , it opens the last opened page

Comment: I found it...
The app.xaml is located in the shared file ...
thanks for the help !
maybe you could put that slight bit of information in your question so other people like myself will see that it is located in the shared folder